# Добавление QwtPlotSpectrogram в проект

Tags: qt

Всем привет)
Я скачал библиотеку `qwt6.0.1` из официального сайта.
Добавил в свой проект пример `Spectogram`. График отображается нормально, НО после добавления требует использовать вместо `slots Q_SLOTS`, вместо `signal Q_SIGNALS`. Как можно сделать так чтобы такого не было?
И иконки (`icons`) к кнопкам (`buttons`) стали не видными. В Дизайнере видит все, потом после запуска иконки не видны...
Кто нибудь с такой проблемой сталкивался?
Я думаю из за файла `example.pri`, там есть еще два файла `qwtconfig.pri` и `qwtbuild.pri`.
Может надо редактировать `example.pri`? Может там много лишнего написано?

```
  //Example.pri
    QWT_ROOT = $${PWD}/..
    include( $${QWT_ROOT}/qwtconfig.pri )
    include( $${QWT_ROOT}/qwtbuild.pri )

TEMPLATE     = app

INCLUDEPATH += $${QWT_ROOT}/src
DEPENDPATH  += $${QWT_ROOT}/src
DESTDIR      = $${QWT_ROOT}/examples/bin

QMAKE_RPATHDIR *= $${QWT_ROOT}/lib

contains(QWT_CONFIG, QwtFramework) {

    LIBS      += -F$${QWT_ROOT}/lib
}

 else {

        LIBS      += -L$${QWT_ROOT}/lib
    }

IPATH       = $${INCLUDEPATH}
qtAddLibrary(qwt)
INCLUDEPATH = $${IPATH}

contains(QWT_CONFIG, QwtSvg) {

    QT += svg
}
else {

    DEFINES += QWT_NO_SVG
}

win32 {
    contains(QWT_CONFIG, QwtDll) {
        DEFINES    += QT_DLL QWT_DLL
    }
}

//qwtbuild.pri
################################################################
# Qwt Widget Library
# Copyright (C) 1997   Josef Wilgen
# Copyright (C) 2002   Uwe Rathmann
#
# This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the Qwt License, Version 1.0
################################################################

######################################################################
# qmake internal options
######################################################################

CONFIG           += qt     
CONFIG           += warn_on
CONFIG           += no_keywords
CONFIG           += silent

######################################################################
# release/debug mode
######################################################################

win32 {
    # On Windows you can't mix release and debug libraries.
    # The designer is built in release mode. If you like to use it
    # you need a release version. For your own application development you
    # might need a debug version. 
    # Enable debug_and_release + build_all if you want to build both.

    CONFIG           += debug_and_release
    CONFIG           += build_all
}
else {

    CONFIG           += release

    VER_MAJ           = $${QWT_VER_MAJ}
    VER_MIN           = $${QWT_VER_MIN}
    VER_PAT           = $${QWT_VER_PAT}
    VERSION           = $${QWT_VERSION}
}

linux-g++ {
    # CONFIG           += separate_debug_info
}

######################################################################
# paths for building qwt
######################################################################

#MOC_DIR      = moc
RCC_DIR      = resources
!debug_and_release {
    OBJECTS_DIR       = obj
}

unix {

    exists( $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT}/libqwt.* ) {

        # On some Linux distributions the Qwt libraries are installed 
        # in the same directory as the Qt libraries. Unfortunately
        # qmake always adds QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT at the beginning of the 
        # linker path, so that the installed libraries will be
        # used instead of the local ones.

        error( "local build will conflict with $${QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT}/libqwt.*" )
    }
}

//qwtconfig.pri
################################################################
# Qwt Widget Library
# Copyright (C) 1997   Josef Wilgen
# Copyright (C) 2002   Uwe Rathmann
#
# This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the Qwt License, Version 1.0
################################################################

QWT_VER_MAJ      = 6
QWT_VER_MIN      = 0
QWT_VER_PAT      = 1
QWT_VERSION      = $${QWT_VER_MAJ}.$${QWT_VER_MIN}.$${QWT_VER_PAT}

######################################################################
# Install paths
######################################################################

QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX = $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]

unix {
    QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX    = /usr/local/qwt-$$QWT_VERSION
}

win32 {
    QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX    = C:/Qwt-$$QWT_VERSION
}

QWT_INSTALL_DOCS      = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/doc
QWT_INSTALL_HEADERS   = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
QWT_INSTALL_LIBS      = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib

######################################################################
# Designer plugin
######################################################################

QWT_INSTALL_PLUGINS   = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/plugins/designer
# QWT_INSTALL_PLUGINS   = $${QT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/plugins/designer

######################################################################
# Features
# When building a Qwt application with qmake you might want to load
# the compiler/linker flags, that are required to build a Qwt application
# from qwt.prf. Therefore all you need to do is to add "CONFIG += qwt" 
# to your project file and take care, that qwt.prf can be found by qmake.
# ( see http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-new-configuration-features )
# I recommend not to install the Qwt features together with the
# Qt features, because you will have to reinstall the Qwt features,
# with every Qt upgrade. 
######################################################################

QWT_INSTALL_FEATURES  = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/features
# QWT_INSTALL_FEATURES  = $${QT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/features

######################################################################
# Build the static/shared libraries.
# If QwtDll is enabled, a shared library is built, otherwise
# it will be a static library.
######################################################################

QWT_CONFIG           += QwtDll

######################################################################
# QwtPlot enables all classes, that are needed to use the QwtPlot 
# widget. 
######################################################################

QWT_CONFIG       += QwtPlot

######################################################################
# QwtWidgets enables all classes, that are needed to use the all other
# widgets (sliders, dials, ...), beside QwtPlot. 
######################################################################

QWT_CONFIG     += QwtWidgets

######################################################################
# If you want to display svg images on the plot canvas, or
# export a plot to a SVG document
######################################################################

QWT_CONFIG     += QwtSvg

######################################################################
# You can use the MathML renderer of the Qt solutions package to 
# enable MathML support in Qwt. Because of license implications
# the ( modified ) code of the MML Widget solution is included and
# linked together with the QwtMathMLTextEngine into an own library. 
# To use it you will have to add "CONFIG += qwtmathml"
# to your qmake project file.
######################################################################

QWT_CONFIG     += QwtMathML

######################################################################
# If you want to build the Qwt designer plugin, 
# enable the line below.
# Otherwise you have to build it from the designer directory.
######################################################################

QWT_CONFIG     += QwtDesigner

######################################################################
# If you want to auto build the examples, enable the line below
# Otherwise you have to build them from the examples directory.
######################################################################

# QWT_CONFIG     += QwtExamples

######################################################################
# When Qt has been built as framework qmake ( qtAddLibrary ) wants 
# to link frameworks instead of regular libs
######################################################################

macx:CONFIG(qt_framework, qt_framework|qt_no_framework) {

    QWT_CONFIG += QwtFramework
}
```

можно ли два .pri файла подключить?
У меня до этого была подключена qwt.pri, для отображения 2д графика

```
//qwt.pri
    QWT_VER = 6.0.2
    contains(QWT_VER,^5\\..*\\..*) {
        VER_SFX     = 5
        UNIX_SFX    = -qt4
    } else {
        VER_SFX     =
        UNIX_SFX    =
    }
    unix {
        QWT_PATH = /usr
        QWT_INC_PATH = $${QWT_PATH}/include/qwt$${UNIX_SFX}
        QWT_LIB  = qwt$${UNIX_SFX}
    }

    win32 {
        win32-x-g++ {
            QWT_PATH = /usr/qwt$${VER_SFX}-win
        } else {
            QWT_PATH = C:/Qt/qwt-$${QWT_VER}
        }
        QWT_INC_PATH = $${QWT_PATH}/include
        CONFIG(debug,debug|release) {
            DEBUG_SFX = d
        } else {
            DEBUG_SFX =
        }
        QWT_LIB = qwt$${DEBUG_SFX}$${VER_SFX}
    }
    INCLUDEPATH += $${QWT_INC_PATH}
    LIBS += -L$${QWT_PATH}/lib -l$${QWT_LIB}

//Вот .pro файл(файл проекта)
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator
#
#-------------------------------------------------
#include( c:/QtSDK/projects/qwt/qwt-6.0.1/qwt-6.0.1/examples/examples.pri )
#greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets'

include( C:/QtSDK/temp3/qwtplot3d/examples/common.pro )
QT       += core gui

TARGET = ButtonMoveArrow
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += ...тут добавлены файлы
HEADERS  += ...тут добавлены файлы 
FORMS    += ...тут добавлены файлы

QWT_LOCATION = c:/Qwt-6.0.1
INCLUDEPATH += $${QWT_LOCATION}/include
LIBS = -L$${QWT_LOCATION}/lib \
     -lqwt

if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) \
        $$member(LIBS, 1)d
}

OTHER_FILES += \
    qwt.pri

#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qwt6

#LIBS += -lqwt6
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Насчет сигналов-слотов может и не подскажу, но с иконками: похоже что потерялись либо файлы (они лежат в директории с примером, а в директории Вашего проекта их соответственно нет и поэтому и отображать нечего), либо неправильно прикручен *.qrc файл из примера к Вашему проекту.

Comment: можно ли два .pri файла добавить? Не будет ли конфликта между в моем случае?
Корректировал вопрос.

Я иконки добавлял через дизайнер, ваше совет возьму в заметку)

Comment: Вопрос решен, оставил старый qwt.pri, и через него построил график.